# Font Previews in <select> dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I've been looking around and there's really not much on how to make font previews (to show the text in the same font they're selecting) in a dropdown list. Can anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Just HTML, if it needs to be done in jQuery or JavaScript that would be fine.

Comment: You will need a Javascript-powered select control to make this work across browsers. Only the modern ones accept individual styling on `<option>`s, and I'm not sure whether `font-face` is supported at all

Comment: Does it have to be a real `select` element? Or would a styled `ul`, or similar, be okay?

Comment: Well as long as a javascript form can get the value of the ul by it's ID (and the value will be a font name), I don't see why it couldn't be a ul.

Comment: I've been writing up a test, and Pekka's bang on. Firefox 3.6 has no problems rendering the `font-family`, but IE 8 won't render it on the `option` tags even if I create a dynamic style sheet. You'll have to fake a `select` menu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To offer an alternative to using *only* a `select` element, that *will* allow for styling the font, and applying other css, while updating a traditional `select` element for submission to the server/script:

#### html:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <select id="fontSelector" name="fontSelector">
        <option value="calibri">Calibri</option>
        <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
        <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
    </select>
</form>

<ul id="fontList">
    <li id="calibri" class="selected">Calibri</li>
    <li id="timesNewRoman">Times New Roman</li>
    <li id="comicSansMS">Comic Sans MS</li>
</ul>
```

#### jQuery:

```
$('#fontList li').click(
    function(){
        var chosen = $(this).index();
        $('#fontSelector option:selected')
            .removeAttr('selected');
        $('#fontSelector option')
            .eq(chosen)
            .attr('selected',true);
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/A5bJg/).

Notes:

1. This assumes that that the order of the `li` elements will be the same as the order of the `option` elements, since the `option` that becomes `selected` is chosen by index (of the `li`).

References:

1. [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
2. [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
3. [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).
4. [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
5. [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
6. [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
7. [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use the **HiGoogleFonts**.

It doesn't load all the fonts as you scroll. It only loads the fonts that are clicked. For font preview , It is using a single image which loads very fast . It has 700+ fonts

[Download it from github](https://github.com/saadqbal/HiGoogleFonts)

[See demo here](https://cdn.rawgit.com/saadqbal/HiGoogleFonts/master/index2.html)